# Is it possible to $compile with angular HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to $compile HTML document,- not element like `$compile` expect?

Problem i'm trying to solve: i have printable form in external .html file and i'd like to include this row: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">`

Right now i can't do that, because `$compile` expect `element` parameter, which one is DOM element and couldn't contain (or simple ignore link to stylesheet).

Template i have:

```
<div>
    <span ng-bind="model.tasks.count"></span>
</div>
```

Template, that i would like to have (my main goal- extract styles into separate file):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="/app/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
        <span ng-bind="model.tasks.count"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example of my code:

```
return $q.all([ getTemplate(), getScope() ]).then(
    function(msg) {
        var element = angular.element(msg[0]); // Now it's DOM element
        $compile(element)(msg[1]); // If i pass HTML document, element goes undefined
        openWindow(element);
    });
```

and openWindow:

```
function openWindow(element) {
    $timeout(function () {
        var html = element.html();

        var _w = window.open();
        _w.document.body.innerHTML = html; // Here i'd like to write complete HTML doc
        _w.print();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to $compile HTML document,- not element like $compile
>   expect?

It isn't really correct, `$compile` expects anything, you can pass the entire html as string to either `angular.element` or `$compile`. But the answer is still no, `$compile` uses jqLite under the hood:

```
  if (!($compileNodes instanceof jqLite)) {
    // jquery always rewraps, whereas we need to preserve the original selector so that we can
    // modify it.
    $compileNodes = jqLite($compileNodes);
  }
  // We can not compile top level text elements since text nodes can be merged and we will
  // not be able to attach scope data to them, so we will wrap them in <span>
  forEach($compileNodes, function(node, index) {
    if (node.nodeType == NODE_TYPE_TEXT && node.nodeValue.match(/\S+/) /* non-empty */ ) {
      $compileNodes[index] = jqLite(node).wrap('<span></span>').parent()[0];
    }
  });
```

And jqLite will treat html document the same way as `jQuery()` - as a collection of top-level elements from `<head>` and `<body`. Surely, `$compile` wasn't intended for compiling whole documents.

If you're after having styles in templates, you could use `<style type="text/css">@import url("...")</style>`.